# Getting a RSS feed from a Sharepoint subsite blog to the main page

Tags: rss

I can not get the rss feed to work, when trying I get the error message:

> Forbidden.

I have already done a lot of research around this and tried Xml without any result. Worth mentioning is that any external RSS works perfectly fine.

My question is simply, is there a way around this? Except for installing kerebros that would be, wich is an option I have found.

I have an idea of perhaps putting the rss from SharePoint on an external site and then pick it up from there to the main page, have anyone attempted this?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, I would try to setup Kerberos.  That's the only way i've gotten this to work in the past.

But I would also back up and say, why do you need to do this?  Can you use the content query webpart to achieve similar results?

Comment: Content query? Explain further please, hehe

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650512.aspx